# Kann "grundlegend" im Komparativ oder Superlativ verwendet werden?

Tags: adjective, comparative

In meiner Bachelorarbeit hatte ich gerade die Situation, dass ich über ein Softwareprodukt in seiner minimalsten Ausführung sprechen möchte. Intuitiv kam mir dabei in den Sinn, das wie folgt zu formulieren:

> In der grundlegendsten Version des Produktes kostet es bereits über 2000€, [...]

Die Formulierung "grundlegenste Version" klingt auf den zweiten Blick<sup>1</sup> allerdings etwas merkwürdig, und ich bin mir unsicher, ob "grundlegend" überhaupt steigerbar ist.

Den Satz habe ich mittlerweile schon zu "In der Basisversion" umformuliert, nichtsdestotrotz interessiert mich allgemein, ob "grundlegendst" im Superlativ verwendet werden kann (bzw. auch "grundlegender" im Komparativ; wenn eine Steigerung möglich ist, sollte beides existieren).

[de.wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/grundlegend) sagt Folgendes, trifft dabei aber keine konkrete Aussage, ob es nun offiziell erlaubt ist oder nicht.

> Anmerkung zur Steigerbarkeit:
>
> Dieses Wort gehört zu der Gruppe von Adjektiven, die von vielen als nicht steigerbar angesehen werden, bei welchen aber dennoch viele Belege von Komparativ und Superlativ existieren. Da der Sprachgebrauch sie kennt, werden die Steigerungsformen hier aufgeführt.

Der Duden trifft ebenfalls keine explizite Aussage, [führt aber keine Steigerungsformen auf](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/grundlegend), wie das bei anderen Begriffen ([[am] intelligent/-er/-esten](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/intelligent)) der Fall ist.

**Ist der Begriff "grundlegend" also steigerbar? Oder ist die Verwendung dieses Wortes im Komparativ/Superlativ lediglich "umgangssprachliche Ignoranz"?**

<sub>1: "auf das zweite Hören"? Egal, nicht das Thema der Frage ^^</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98019/discussion-on-question-by-pixelmaster-kann-grundlegend-im-komparativ-oder-supe).

Answer (score 4):

**Grammatikalisch gesehen: Ja.**

- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/grundlegend) sagt, es gibt Nachweise für Komparativ und
  Superlativ.
- [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grundlegend%2Cgrundlegender%2Cam%20grundlegendsten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrundlegend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrundlegender%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20grundlegendsten%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgrundlegend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrundlegender%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20grundlegendsten%3B%2Cc0) findet durchaus einige Stellen, wobei die Fundstellen für den Komparativ alle nur Deklinationen sind und daher eher irreführend. Der Superlativ kommt anscheinend aber durchaus vor.
- [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/grundlegend:A) ist anderer Meinung und erwähnt nur den Positiv

Hilfreich ist vielleicht das Aufsuchen eines Synonyms - hier **fundamental**.

- [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fundamental) meint ohne Einschränkung, dass Komparativ und
  Superlativ existieren
- [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fundamental%2C%20fundamentaler%2Cam%20fundamentalsten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfundamental%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfundamentaler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20fundamentalsten%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfundamental%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfundamentaler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20fundamentalsten%3B%2Cc0) findet auch viele Fundstellen, mit Komparativ (siehe Einschränkung oben) und Superlativ ungefähr im gleichen Anteil wie bei *grundlegend*.
- [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/fundamental:A) sagt, Komparativ und Superlativ existieren, und zwar ohne Einschränkungen

**Logisch gesehen: Zweifelhaft**

Eine *Grundlage* ist per Definition etwas, was ganz unten als Basis/Fundament unter etwas anderem liegt und ist damit an sich logisch schon eine Art Superlativ. Das *Fundament eines Fundaments* (das "fundamentaler oder "grundlegender" als das darüber liegende sein könnte) findet sich höchst selten, per Definition gibt es unter einem Fundament/einer Grundlage nichts anderes. Die Stellen, wo Komparativ oder Superlativ logisch sinnvoll einsetzbar wären, halten sich meiner Meinung nach in sehr engen Grenzen. Die *ngrams*-Fundstellen für beide Wörter fand ich alle nicht besonders stilsicher.

Comment: kann es sein, dass du beim Thema "ngrams" Komparativ und Superlativ verwechselt hast? Wenn ich den Link aufrufe, ist der Superlativ ("am grundlegendsten") kaum vertreten.

Comment: +1 für die differenzierte Betrachtung.

Comment: Nein, kann nicht sein. ngrams gibt keine klugen Antworten, wenn man sie nicht wenigstens stichprobenartig anschaut - Die verlinkten Fundstellen von *grundlegender* sind alle deklinierte Positive.

Answer (score 0):

## Ja.

Nehmen wir als Beispiel die Vorlesungen in einem Studium. Es gibt (in diesem Beispiel) die Vorlesung Kryptographie (= digitale Verschlüsselungstechnik), sowie Mathematik I und II.

Mathematik I ist die Voraussetzung, um Mathematik II zu besuchen, während die Kryptographie-Vorlesung Stoff aus beiden Mathematik-Vorlesungen referenziert, sodass beide eine Voraussetzung für den Besuch der Kryptographie-Vorlesung sind.

Mathematik I ist ganz eindeutig Grundlagenwissen im Studium; nichtsdestotrotz ist für Kryptographie und andere Vorlesungen auch Mathematik II eine Voraussetzung.

**Im Vergleich mit Kryptographie sind also beide Mathematik-Vorlesungen "grundlegend" - Mathematik I ist allerdings "grundlegender", da es auch Grundlage für Mathematik II ist.**

"Am grundlegendsten" müsste folglich auch existieren, wobei schwer festzulegen ist, was in die Kategorie fällt. Ein vorhandenes Abitur? Kenntnisse der Sprache, in der die Vorlesung(en) gehalten wird/werden? Am Leben zu sein? Dass das Universum existiert?

So oder so ist "grundlegend" somit steigerbar.

Comment: *grundlegend* wird bisweilen so verwendet, ich finde auch Belege dafür. Gerade das Beispiel "Mathematik" ist aber eins, wo man sich bei einer logischen und in sich schlüssigen Wissenschaft auch einer logischen Sprache bedienen sollte und hinterlässt bei mir ein Jucken.